# Trigger Continuous Delivery every GitHub Commit

Tags: git, github, jenkins

How to configure GitHub service hook to trigger our builds on jenkins .

I am facing some problem and attached screen shot below.

[image]

Note: Manually trigger is working.

Comment: "Manually trigger is working" but are there some commits on master?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to be authorized to call jenkins hook. And have your job properly configured. See build triggers section in your build configuration.

```
http://<username>:<api-token>@<jenkins-server>/job/<job-name>/build
```

Answer (score 0):

It is ridiculous, but I wrote blog post with same name some time ago:
http://lkrnac.net/blog/2014/03/continuous-delivery/

Exact steps how to integrate Jenkins with GitHub (with screenshots) are in second section. I copied them from my blog (But I suggest to go directly to blog post -> because of screenshots):

Jenkins – GitHub integration

- Blocking requirement here is to have Jenkins server accessible from web. If you can’t for whatever reason, you must stick with polling the source control in Jenkins.
- Install GitHub plugin into Jenkins
- Generate Personal access token in GitHub for Jenkins. This can be found under “Edit Your Profile” -> “Applications”
- Set up GitHub plugin to use generated token in Jenkins. You can find this section in “Manage Jenkins” -> “Configure System” -> “GitHub Web Hook”. Note that you don’t need to use password. API URL is “https://api.github.com”
- Create WebHook in Github. Open repository -> “Settings” -> “Webhooks & Services” -> “Create Webhook”
- Use Jenkins URL with suffix “/github-webhook”. Jenkins will replace automatically as you configure jobs, so that it’s not needed to create GitHub hook for each Jenkins job
- After creation you can test webhook via three dots in “Recent Deliveries”. HTML error code “302 Found” means that it’s working fine (even when GitHub highlights it with exclamation mark).
- Finally enable GitHub triggering in Jenkins job